# What is wrong in this elastic search query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, term-query

I can't understand why I have no results? Using ES 2.

```
"query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "technical.techcolor": "red"
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

And here is the info from db that I am searching against.

```
{"technical":
        [{
         "techname22": "test",
         "techcolor":"red",
         "techlocation": "usa"
        }],
    "audio":
        {
        "someAudioMetadata": "test"
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you share your mapping ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CF9LEn6v

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified your mapping, I am considering the following mapping.

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "company": {
      "properties": {
        "technical": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {

        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "technical",
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "technical.techcolor": "red"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "demos",
                "_type": "company",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "technical": [
                        {
                            "techname22": "test",
                            "techcolor": "red",
                            "techlocation": "usa"
                        }
                    ],
                    "audio": {
                        "someAudioMetadata": "test"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

To know more about nested datatype you can refer to this official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/nested.html) and for Query and Filter Context refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-filter-context.html)

Comment: @Ramix did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you and if it's helpful, please don't forget to upvote and accept :)